# how do I change the icon of blank page?

Tags: html

When I open one of my HTML documents in Google Chrome, the left of opened tab doesn't have any ICON on the tab, how do I set that?

Comment: Put a image named `favicon.ico` in the same directory where the HTML file in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a favicon image with .ico at the end.
Add it like:

```
<head>
<title>~~~~</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set title and favicon for your html in the head section of html:

```
<head>
<title>Your custom title</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
</head>
```

and put the favicon.png in same folder of html page.